# Is there any way to add column name in all the row of a dataframe based on a specific condition in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like:

```
   Name  Age  Class Maths English Physics Bio Chemistry
    A     13   7      1    None     None   1    None
    B     17   10    None   1        1    None  None
```

I want to add a new column named Subject, that should include the column names(having 1) as the values of the subject field, shown below:

```
   Name  Age  Class    Subject     
    A     13   7     Maths, Bio
    B     17   10    English, Physics
```

I tried using a few ways, but it's taking longer than usual.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) with `lambda` function.

```py
df['Subject'] = (df == '1').apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[x]), axis=1)
df = df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,-1]]
df
  Name  Age  Class           Subject
0    A   13      7        Maths, Bio
1    B   17     10  English, Physics
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#extract subjects columns
subjects = df.iloc[:,3:].columns

#identify columns that are not na per row
notnull = df.filter(subjects).notna().to_numpy()

#get the non null columns and assign to subject column
#... still thinking of a non python loop ... glad if anyone can drop a better replacement
df['subjects'] = [subjects[row].str.cat(sep=', ') for row in notnull]

#drop subjects list
df.drop(subjects,axis=1)

    Name    Age Class   subjects
0   A        13   7     Maths, Bio
1   B        17   10    English, Physics
```

Answer (score 1):

One, easy to read method:

```
subjects = ['Maths', 'English', 'Physics', 'Bio', 'Chemistry']

df['Subject'] = ""
for row in range(len(df.index)):
    output = []
    for i, col in enumerate(df.loc[df.index[row], subjects]):
        if col == 1:
            output.append(str(subjects[i]))
    df.at[df.index[row], 'Subject'] = ", ".join(output)
```